# How to get eSIM phone number from the device?

Tags: android, phone-number

I want to get an eSIM phone number from the device.

I am using the SubscriptionInfo class to get the phone number but it always returns null.

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionMgr = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo = subscriptionMgr.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(simIndex);

String phoneNumber = subscriptionInfo.getNumber()
```

I also give the permission in the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to check if permission is granted.

```
public void getSIMNumber() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        //TODO check if permission is Granted

        List<SubscriptionInfo> subsInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        Log.d("Test", "Current list = " + subsInfoList);

        for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subsInfoList) {

            String number = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();

            Log.d("Test", " Number is  " + number);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had already allowed permission from app setting. This API is working when I have a physical sim card in the device. but when I switched the carrier profile with eSIM  then I am not able to get the phone number from device.